# I can't make Ubuntu ask for a password anymore!

Tags: login, google-chrome, password, keyrings, auto-login

I enabled auto-login some time ago and now I can't disable it. I've switched it at the user accounts options and it doesn't work! It says "off", but it's actually still on. And I also can't make Google Chrome stop asking my login keyring. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop Google Chrome asking for password do as follows:
I think the simplest way is to set the password for the keyring to an empty password -- you will not be prompted for a password then:

- Open Applications -> Accessories -> Password and Encryption Keys
- Right-click on the "login" keyring. Select "Change password"
- Enter your old password and leave the new password blank
- Press ok, read the security warning, think about it and if you still
  want    to get rid of this dialog, choose "use unsafe
  storage/continue".

*Again, as the message says: This will expose all your passwords (e.g. email passwords) that you chose to save in the default keyring to anyone using your computer or having access to your files and is therefore not recommended.*

---

To solve autologin problem. Open System Settings. click on User Accounts. click on Unlock(on top-right corner). Then toggle auto-login option. Then log-out and login again. See whether this is working according to auto-login option you set.

Comment: Thanks a lot man!!! This was really getting on my nerves.

Comment: @pedro.afonso please vote up my answer and accept it as your answer to problem by clicking below vote sign

Comment: Done! Sorry, I was supposed to check this out when I got home the other day, and just completely forgot. Anyway, thanks again for the help m8!